# Are there different types of NAs? My dataset's NA counts with rattle vary?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data, rattle

I'm using the rattle package to do some data cleaning and I'm consider the first variable X in my dataset. It reports, when I do in the first tab, the "Data" tab, I get some basic  of the dataset and it says that variable X that has 1243 missing values. This is also the value that I get if I use `sum(is.na(my_df[,1]))`.

On the next tab, the "Explore" tab, when I check "Summary" it now says that I have just 942 NAs in variable X.

How can I makes sense of these different numbers? I manually browsed a bit through my dataset and looked at some rows that had NAs and those NAs all look the same (I understand that sometimes there are different types of NAs).

(Side question: `sum(is.na(my_df[,1]), na.rm = FALSE)` and `sum(is.na(my_df[,1]),na.rm = TRUE)` also both produce the same number 1243, why? I would have expected that one gives me `length(my_df[,1])-1243`.)

---

**EDIT** Here is the dataset that has this problem: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cf454b2c12857a4e3770102a7222422f20171019153755/516fb0 .

The numbers in that are slightly different, instead of 1243, we have 88 NAs according to the "Data" tab in rattle() (or, equivalently, according to `summary(ten_df)` ), and 62 NAs according to the "Explore" with checked Summary tab.

But now I suspect my dataset is broken because before uploading the complete one, I wanted to originally only upload one illustrative column. But when I execute

```
ten_df = read.csv("ten.csv",sep=";") 
my_df = as.data.frame(ten_df[,3])
```

since I want to look at the third column with `var2` and `my_df` was what I wanted to upload originally, the last command returns an error

```
Warning messages:
1: In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Also, when selecting afterward my_df to analyse it with rattle, rattle says "0 input variable" in the bar at the bottom where it is giving feedback. How can this be?

Comment: As for your side question, `is.na` can only return `TRUE/FALSE`, argument `na.rm` is irrelevant. To see this try `x <- c(1:3, NaN, NA, 4, 5, NA); sum(is.na(x))`. As for the difference in reported values of missing values, it's hard to tell without seeing the data. I would trust `summary(X)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to contain an actual snippet of a few lines of data (MCVE) illustrating the discrepancy in NA counts with rattle, not just a link to a huge file on wetransfer.com where we have to accept their TOS.

Answer (score 10):

`?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value
>   indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw.
>   There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and
>   NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing
>   values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

```
class(NA)             # "logical"
class(NA_integer_)    # "integer"
class(NA_real_)       # "numeric"
class(NA_complex_)    # "complex"
class(NA_character_)  # "character"
is.na(NA)             # TRUE
is.na(NA_integer_)    # TRUE
is.na(NA_real_)       # TRUE
is.na(NA_complex_)    # TRUE
is.na(NA_character_)  # TRUE
identical(NA,NA_integer_)    # FALSE
identical(NA,NA_real_)       # FALSE
identical(NA,NA_complex_)    # FALSE
identical(NA,NA_character_)  # FALSE
identical(NA_character_,as.character(NA)) # TRUE
identical(NA_real_,as.numeric(NA))        # TRUE
identical(as.logical(NA_real_),NA)        # TRUE
```

So NA is a `logical`. So why do we use NA pretty much everywhere without worrying about the class ? because of coercion rules :

```
class(c(NA,1)[1])                # "numeric"
identical(c(NA,1),c(NA_real_,1)) # TRUE
c(NA_character_,1)               # [1] NA  "1"
```

Depending on `class`, `NA` might also be printed differently

Now back to your question, I can't answer the first one because you offer no reproducible data, but as for why `sum(is.na(my_df[,1]), na.rm = FALSE)` and `sum(is.na(my_df[,1]),na.rm = TRUE)`, it's because  `is.na(my_df[,1])` is only made of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, not `NA`s.

You can also try `length(na.omit(my_df[,1]))`.

**EDIT:**

A given column of a `data.frame` has only elements of one class, so you won't have different `NA_character_` and `NA_real_` in the same column.

Something that happens often however is that you'll have some strings whose value is `"NA"`, you shouldn't of course expect `is.na` to detect those. In these cases you can use `df[df == "NA"] <- NA` to have regular `NA`s instead of `"NA"` strings in your `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good, in-depth answer so far, I learned a lot from you! I wish I could upvote, but I can do that only after I have 15 rep points; once I reach that I'll try to upvote retrospectively. I also uploaded the dataset, could you have a look at it, so that the first answer can be answered as well?

Comment: unfortunately I can't access this website from my work computer, but my guess is that `sum(is.na(df[,1]))` will give you the correct answer, and for some reason, the alternative values you find are either not up to date or just estimation. It would help to really see a contradiction through code commands and not what you see in tabs :). You can also cut your data set to a reasonable size and explore it manually, it's already not that big.